# How to find closest tag to inner text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find a way to get the tag containing a specific text value, the problem is that contains returns the element if it has a descendant with the text.  I only want the one specifically containing the text.

For example:

```
<table>
    <tr id='tag1'>
        <td>First Name $first$</td>
        <td>Last Name $last$</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to find all the tags where there is text wrapped in $.   Using :contains gives me TABLE and TR tags.  I only want the TD tags.

Mind you, these could be DIVs instead of TDs, so I can't specifically search on TD either.

Anyone have some slick ideas?

Comment: Why the content between $ and $, there might be a better approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the interest of speed and dealing with embedded child elements, you may find that using plain JS and searching just text nodes is both faster and more practical.  I have a `treewalk()` function that I've tweaked to call a callback on all text nodes in some parent then you can use the callback to do whatever you want in those text nodes.

Here's a working demo of this concept that replaces `$first$` and `$last$` with values from a map object: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/d2fsE/.

And here's more generic code that just builds you a list of nodes and matches:

```
var treeWalkTextNodes = (function() {
    // create closure for constants
    var skipTags = {"SCRIPT": true, "IFRAME": true, "OBJECT": true, 
        "EMBED": true, "STYLE": true, "LINK": true, "META": true};
    return function(parent, fn, data) {
        var node = parent.firstChild, nextNode;
        while (node && node != parent) {
            if (node.nodeType === 3) {
                if (fn(node, data) === false) {
                    return false ;
                }
            }
            // if element with children and not a skipTag type element, then
            //     iterate through it's children
            if (node.nodeType === 1 && node.firstChild && !(node.tagName && skipTags[node.tagName])) {
                node = node.firstChild;
            } else  if (node.nextSibling) {
                node = node.nextSibling;
            } else {
                // no child and no nextsibling
                // find parent that has a nextSibling
                while ((node = node.parentNode) != parent) {
                    if (node.nextSibling) {
                        node = node.nextSibling;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})();

function replace$Data(parent, map) {
    var dollars = /\$(.*?)\$/;
    treeWalkTextNodes(parent, function(node, data) {
        // node is the text node
        // node.parentNode is the element containing the text node
        var str, found = false;
        str = node.nodeValue.replace(dollars, function(match, p1) {
            if (p1 in map) {
                found = true;
                return map[p1];
            } else {
                return match;
            }
        });
        if (found) {
            node.nodeValue = str;
        }
    });
}


// then to call this, you would do something like this:
var matchMap = {
    first: "John",
    last: "Kennedy"
};
replace$Data(document.body, matchMap);
```

You can obviously implement your own logic inside the callback function - I've just chosen to show an implementation where it replaces the text between the $ signs with other text from a map.